# Can you change the cursor color in a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, uikit

Is it possible to override the color of the cursor and autocorrection bubbles in a UITextView? This is done in the built-in Notes application, but I don't know if it was done by public means or not.

I can't find any reference to this in any documentation, so I'm worried that it's a private API set in the UIKeyboard or something. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: ATTENTION, PEOPLE OF THE FUTURE: this is easy in iOS 7. It's just the `tintColor` of the text view. Things were not so simple in 2009.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this question is already answered here are some **terrific** (read private) methods of `UITextInputTraits` (tested in iOS5 and 6b :)
I assume people reading this are not targeting the AppStore :p

### Some of them are:

```
UITextInputTraits *inputTraits = [_textView textInputTraits];
UIColor *purpleColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[inputTraits setInsertionPointColor:purpleColor];
[inputTraits setInsertionPointWidth:1]; // Read below note
[inputTraits setSelectionHighlightColor:[purpleColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1]];
[inputTraits setSelectionDragDotImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CoolHandle"]];
[inputTraits setSelectionBarColor:purple];
```

`insertionPointWidth:` apparently has no effect. You need to override `caretRectForPosition:` (method of `UITextInput` protocol) in your `UITextView` subclass.

### Result:

[image: Almost lickable]

---

#### Also these are interesting:

```
[inputTraits setAcceptsFloatingKeyboard:NO];
[inputTraits setAcceptsSplitKeyboard:NO];
```

Use these last two carefully because other text views/fields could accept floating or split keyboards and the keyboard might not update correctly when your textview with the *customized* input traits becomes the first responder.

#### To get a full method list:

```
- (void)printMethodsOfClass:(Class)class
{
    unsigned int methodCount = 0;
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(class));
    Method *mlist = class_copyMethodList(class, &methodCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < methodCount; ++i){
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(mlist[i])));
    }
    NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------------------");
    free(mlist);
}

[self printMethodsOfClass:[[textview textInputTraits] class]];
```

Answer (score 3):

On iOS 7+ this is now accomplished by setting the `tintColor` property on your text field.

Comment: how can we set cursor color for IOS 6?

Comment: I am not aware of a supported way to do it on iOS 6.

Comment: @jeffamaphoneThanks for your response.. I am using code  [[textField valueForKey:@"textInputTraits"] setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"insertionPointColor"]; for iOS 6. Can you please let me know that using this code my app will have approve to publish in App Store Thanks!

Comment: Only Apple can tell you that.  If you do that, you should put it behind a check for iOS 6 and use `tintColor` on more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link that described the "hidden" `UIKeyboard` magic. Looks like `UITextTraits` has a `CaretColor` property. Sadly, I don't think messing with this would make it through Apple's review process. Unless they didn't notice? It's possible...

http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs112/interface_u_i_keyboard.html